# eglot mode map keybindings not showing

Tags: key-bindings, eglot

I'm trying to setup bindings for eglot to show when `eglot-mode-map` is activated, but the keys never seem to be available after the lsp attaches.

im defining my leader key using general:

```
(general-define-key
         :states '(normal insert motion emacs)
         :keymaps 'override
         :prefix-map 'leader-map
         :prefix "SPC"
         :non-normal-prefix "M-SPC")
    (general-create-definer leader-def :keymaps 'leader-map)
    (leader-def "" nil)
```

and then setting up eglot like this (use-package comes from elpaca):

```
(use-package eglot
            :demand t
            :defer t
            :config 
             (setq-default eglot-workspace-configuration
             '((:pylsp . (:configurationSources ["flake8"]
             :plugins (
                     :pycodestyle (:enabled :json-false)
                     :mccabe (:enabled :json-false)
                     :pyflakes (:enabled :json-false)
                     :flake8 (:enabled :json-false
                     :maxLineLength 88)
                     :ruff (:enabled t
                     :lineLength 88)
                     :pydocstyle (:enabled t
                             :convention "google")
                     :yapf (:enabled :json-false)
                     :autopep8 (:enabled :json-false)
                     :black (:enabled f
                             :line_length 88
                             :cache_config t))))))
            )
    (add-hook 'python-ts-mode-hook 'eglot-ensure)
    (add-hook 'typescript-ts-mode-hook 'eglot-ensure)

    (leader-def
        :keymaps 'eglot-mode-map
        :wk-full-keys nil
        "g"     (cons "lsp" (make-sparse-keymap))
        "ge" '(eldoc :wk "errors")
        "ga" '(eglot-code-actions :wk "code actions")
        "gR" '(eglot-rename :wk "lsp rename")
        "gd" '(xref-find-definitions :wk "definitions")
        "gD" '(xref-find-declaration :wk "declaration")
        "gr" '(xref-find-references :wk "references")
        "gt" '(eglot-find-typeDefinition :wk "type definition")
        "gi" '(eglot-find-implementation :wk "implementation")
        )
```

if I remove `:keymaps 'eglot-mode-map` then the binds show fine so it seems like an issue of the keymap not being active when the lsp attaches?

EDIT:

Just noticed that the keybinds are being set up, but not under my leader key. If I press "g" I can see some of the binds there, so this is maybe more of a general problem. How do I fix the binds so that only show up under the SPC leader?